# CSS Word Break and Word Wrap is not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, datatables

May I seek help,
Word Wrap or Word break is not working on my string,

This is the text,
The company's revenue has been increasing for the last five years with an overall growth of 49% between 2015 and 2019. Revenue increased 7% to $426.4 million for the year ended December 29, 2019, as compared to $398.2 million for the year ended December 30, 2018. The increase was primarily driven by $28.5 million in incremental revenue from an additional 359 operating weeks provided by new restaurants opened during and subsequent to the year ended December 30, 2018 as well as an increase in its comparable restaurant sales. Net income increased by $0.7 million and 12% to $6.2 million for the year ended December 29, 2019 as compared to $5.5 million during the comparable period in 2018. This was due to the increase in depreciation and amortization costs, as well as the increase in income tax benefits. The company's cash equivalents at the end of 2019 totaled $10.1 million, an increase of $2 million from the previous year. Operating activities generated $43.4 million, while investing activities used $33.3 million. Financing activities used another $8.3 million primarily for common stock repurchases and line of credit payments.

This is my CSS

```css
.txt {
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  min-height:150px;
  max-width:150px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Here is my HTML

```html
<td>
   <div class="txt">{{ $value }}</div>
</td>
```

What happens is

[image]

The string is not breaking it shows in one line, even if overflow is hidden or not,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word wrap column data in Javascript datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275446/word-wrap-column-data-in-javascript-datatable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to work fine:

```css
.txt {
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  min-height:150px;
  max-width:150px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="txt">
The company's revenue has been increasing for the last five years with an overall growth of 49% between 2015 and 2019. Revenue increased 7% to $426.4 million for the year ended December 29, 2019, as compared to $398.2 million for the year ended December 30, 2018. The increase was primarily driven by $28.5 million in incremental revenue from an additional 359 operating weeks provided by new restaurants opened during and subsequent to the year ended December 30, 2018 as well as an increase in its comparable restaurant sales. Net income increased by $0.7 million and 12% to $6.2 million for the year ended December 29, 2019 as compared to $5.5 million during the comparable period in 2018. This was due to the increase in depreciation and amortization costs, as well as the increase in income tax benefits. The company's cash equivalents at the end of 2019 totaled $10.1 million, an increase of $2 million from the previous year. Operating activities generated $43.4 million, while investing activities used $33.3 million. Financing activities used another $8.3 million primarily for common stock repurchases and line of credit payments.
</div>
```

Did you "inspect" your div to see if some other css rule is messing the thing?

[image]

When you hit <kbd>F12</kbd> in your browser and then select your `div` either by clicking on it (1 or 2), you'll see what styles are applied to it in 3.
You'll likely see <strike>`word-break: break-all;`</strike> or the same with `word-wrap` because it is overriden by some other rule.

Comment: I cant find out the problem yet, i am using datatable but it still not showing properly even if i remove the class,

Answer (score 2):

you can do this instead of nesting div into td

```css
.txt {
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  min-height:150px;
  max-width:150px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="txt">skdjfhskadjfhsdlkajfhdsakljfhsdakjfhslkadjfhsdalkjfhsadlkjfhsdalkjfhsadlkjfhsdakljfhsdalkjfhsadlkjfhsdalkjfhsladkjfhslakjfhlskadjfh</td>
   <tr>
</table>
```